# What are the number of solutions of $11^x+13^x+17^x-19^x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

My attempt: $ 11^x+13^x+17^x-19^x=0\implies (\frac{11}{19})^x+(\frac{13}{19})^x+(\frac{17}{19})^x=1 $.

Now taking limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$,we get $0=1$,which is absurd.Hence,the equation has no solution.

Is it correct??

Comment: there is a real solution

Comment: $11^x+13^x+17^x-19^x$ is positive for $x=0$ and negative for large $x$ and is continuous so there is a positive solution

Comment: a numerical method is a good choice

Comment: No, it is not correct.  The limit only shows that there are no solutions for $x$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Why does the limit mean that there is no solution? All it really shows is that there aren't infinitely large solutions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)= 11^x+13^x+17^x-19^x=19^x[(\frac{11}{19})^x+(\frac{13}{19})^x+(\frac{17}{19})^x-1]$.

Clearly,$g(x)=(\frac{11}{19})^x+(\frac{13}{19})^x+(\frac{17}{19})^x-1$ is a strictly decreasing function.Also,$\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)=-1 $ & $\lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)=\infty$.Thus $f(x)=0$ has exactly one solution.

Comment: Also $g(x)$ is continuous. Also $19^x>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Also writing strictly* decreasing would be better.

Answer (score 0):

As you have been said

$$ 
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 
\Big( 
(\frac{11}{19})^x+(\frac{13}{19})^x+(\frac{17}{19})^x 
\Big) =0;
$$

---

this means that there is an ***upper bound

for the set of solutions*** to the eqation 
$(\frac{11}{19})^x+(\frac{13}{19})^x+(\frac{17}{19})^x=1 $;

---

you can take $5$ as an upper bound, but this is not sharp.